# DataTable Jquery Column Right Align Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

> Column Alignment

```
columnDefs: [
    { targets: [1, 2], className: "cssMyRightAlign" },
],
```

> CSS

```
.cssMyRightAlign{
    text-align: right;
}
```

But its not aligning column 1 & 2 in right.

Codepen Link
https://codepen.io/Sixthsense6/pen/KKeRPXJ

Comment: please can you reproduce in codepen or codesandbox and share the link

Comment: Have you inspected the column and see if it gets the text-align or if another class is overruling your class?

Comment: I've just tested it, and it works just fine for me

Comment: @Sixthsense You haven't include either jquery or datatable js in your codepen. After including those it works just fine.

Comment: Its working in codepen after adding the references.  Will dig my project and find out why it is not working in my VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally traced the root cause of the issue.

I stored the JavaScript in separate file and linked it in my Web Page.  If I keep the JS in webpage itself then it's working fine.

Storing the Js in separate file and linking the same in webpage header or body is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `.cssMyRightAlign` is overwritten by a selector with higher precedence. Try adding the `!important` keyword to it like so:

```
.cssMyRightAlign{
    text-align: right !important;
}
```